# How do I check or ignore a missing DLL when making a shared library in CMake?

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, shared-libraries, cross-platform

PROBLEM: I would like to ignore 'dll not found' errors and continue code execution that does not rely on that library.

I understand this is asking alot, but there's no definitive guide on shared libraries and the mess of conversations out there are confusing. I have gathered that there are three types of libraries that CMake is aware of:

- Static: Linked into executable on compile.
- Shared: UNIX: loadable whenever, WINDOWS: requires a symbols STATIC library to be linked on compile that maps out the DLL.
- Module: Runtime loaded shared library, of which I'm still in the process of understanding.

I'm using the CMake 'GenerateExportHeader' to make my life easier in producing shared libraries. This works. I can even version those libraries to change them on the fly. What I'm having trouble figuring out, however, is how to check and possibly ignore the error if the dll is not found:

"The code execution cannot proceed because xxx.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."

I have tried putting try/catch blocks in the include/object creation. Google foo didn't find anything.

I have looked into "MODULE" type shared library, but I was hoping to avoid the mess that is '__declspec' and loadable libraries.

CMake's 'GenerateExportHeader' is very very nice, and if what I'm asking for isn't possible without manually exporting symbols that's fine, but I thought I might ask the gurus out there.

So.... The code:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
...
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
set(BUILD_TYPE SHARED)
set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)
include(GenerateExportHeader)

...

# Create the library.
add_library(${NAME} ${BUILD_TYPE}
    ${SOURCES}
)

# Visual Studio Source Tree and filters.
source_group(TREE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} FILES ${SOURCES})
set_property(TARGET ${NAME} PROPERTY FOLDER "${NAME}")

if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER(${NAME}
    BASE_NAME ${NAME}
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME ${NAME}_EXPORTS
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${NAME}_EXPORTS.h
    STATIC_DEFINE SHARED_EXPORTS_BUILT_AS_STATIC)
endif(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)

target_include_directories(${NAME} PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/public>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:public>
    PRIVATE private
)

# Link to other libraries.
target_link_libraries(${NAME}
    ${EXAMPLE_LIBRARY}
)

# 'make install' to correct locations.
install(TARGETS ${NAME} EXPORT ${NAME}Config
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin) # For windows.
install(DIRECTORY public/ DESTINATION include)
# 'public'/ project, 'include' for install.

# Importable from the install directory.
# Configs in per-project dir.
install (EXPORT ${NAME}Config DESTINATION share/${NAME}/cmake)
# Importable from the build directory.
export(TARGETS ${NAME} FILE ${NAME}Config.cmake)

# Library Testing/Future unit tests.
set(TESTING_PRIVATE
    Tests/Main.cpp
)
set(TESTING_PUBLIC

)
set(TESTING_COLLECTIVE
    ${TESTING_PRIVATE}
    ${TESTING_PUBLIC}
)

add_executable(${NAME}Develop
    ${TESTING_COLLECTIVE}
)
set_property(TARGET ${NAME}Develop PROPERTY FOLDER "${NAME}")

target_include_directories(${NAME}Develop
    PUBLIC ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/exports
)

if(NOT BUILD_MODULAR_LIBS)
target_link_libraries(${NAME}Develop
    ${NAME}
)
endif(NOT BUILD_MODULAR_LIBS)
```

My code does not have anything specific in it, so for the purposes of this question I simplified a test case.

library.h:

```
#pragma once

namespace Library
{

class Library
{
public:

    void testing();

};

} // namespace Library
```

Library.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Library.h"

namespace Library
{

void Library::testing()
{
    std::cout << "Library API: Hello, world!.... VERSIONED!" << std::endl;
}

} // namespace Library
```

Test/Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

// Tried different error handling, I think I need preprocessors here for this... google didn't help.
// I feel that I should be referencing the DLL, not the header
// and I couldn't find information in wikis or CMake documentation.
#include "Library.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // The same applies for these two lines.
    Library::Library test;
    test.testing();

    std::cout << "Press any key to exit..." << std::endl;
    _getch();

    return 0;

}
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

- Putting try/catch blocks around code that references the library. EDIT: Yes I know this is bad and probably would never work, but I didn't know if something internal might be calling a library load.
- Compiling a version of my program with and without the option libraries. (Honestly... this is bad... very bad... preprocessor directives can solve this, but this means each person were they to want a tailored version without certain libraries would have to build themselves rather than just dropping the dlls they'd like in there, which is what I would like to do.)
- Manual '__declspec' declarations to do this manually, which works but what I would like (if possible) to avoid. There's enough information out there that I was able to piece this together, and am willing to do, but the idea really is to write the code WITH classes just like the executable or a library in what (in c++ terms) would be called plain english.

That last point is really what I'm trying to accomplish. I'd like to be able to write c++ code, and make it readable to other developers, without having to manage some of the more complicated features including platform specific shared library loading.

Comment: With "normal" shared libraries, searching for the library at *runtime* is performed by a *dynamic loader*. If the loader fails, the executable even **hasn't started**. There is no other behavior of the loader in the absence of the library. If you want to proceed even without the library, you have no choice but load it by yourself **dynamically**, as a 'MODULE' library. Note, that module library cannot export symbols for others: you should manually extract these symbols from the library at runtime.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Your first two sentences made it click for me. Is this something out of the realm of modification? I'm not against building a plugin MODULE loader, I was just hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Hm, I have found myself to not understand your purpose clearly. What I understand: You distribute a library `A`, which uses (in main configuration) the library `B`, which should be preliminary installed on the user's machine. You may prepare configuration of `A`, which doesn't use `B`, thus doesn't require it. Can user use library `B` via your distribution? Or you wrap all `B` methods which user is allowed to use? Does interface of your `A` library depend on presence of `B`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Library A has functionality that depends on B, but which isn't required to serve it's normal purpose. If B is missing, features specific to B simply aren't available rather than the whole application/library. EDIT: I do have my own plugin system, now, so this works as I'm manually loading my library at runtime. I just feel like this could/should have a much simpler implementation.